# Sqoop Tar ball unpacking

Tags: linux, tar, sqoop

I'm working through the [installation directions](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html) for Sqoop:

> Sqoop server supports multiple Hadoop versions. However as Hadoop
>   major versions are not compatible with each other, Sqoop have multiple
>   binary artefacts - one for each supported major version of Hadoop. You
>   need to make sure that you’re using appropriated binary artifact for
>   your specific Hadoop version. To install Sqoop server decompress
>   appropriate distribution artifact in location at your convenience and
>   change your working directory to this folder.

## Decompress Sqoop distribution tarball

tar -xvf sqoop--bin-hadoop.tar.gz

## Move decompressed content to any location

mv sqoop--bin-hadoop.tar.gz /usr/lib/sqoop

## Change working directory

cd /usr/lib/sqoop

//END OF DIRECTIONS...

The first step is confusing.  I think "tar -xvf ..." decompresses the files and shoots them off to some location which I did not specify.  When I ran the command I saw a ton of file names listed with no particular direction as to what was being done to them.  E.G.

> [root@sandbox lib]# tar -xvf sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200.tar.gz
>   sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin/sqoop-sys.sh
>   sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin/sqoop.sh
> ...and so on

Then I ran "mv .." to move the tar file.  (Not sure why this wasn't listed as step 1).  Finally, I changed the directory to /sqoop.  When I run `ls` I do not see my files listed.

What am I missing here?  I'm not strong with Linux so maybe I just totally missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the tarball instead of the files. The files should be at the original location of the tarball.

You could tell tar where to unpack your files:

```
  mkdir /usr/lib/sqoop/
  tar -xvf sqoop--bin-hadoop.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/sqoop/
```

Comment: Great answer!  I didn't know the directory needed an ending slash.  Of note, the files extracted to a folder which contained the extracted files `sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200` in my case.  Also, the file extractions are listed as relative paths.

Comment: The trailing slash is mostly optional, but there are cases in which you do need to specify it. It is good practice to always use it.